# Vue todolist toggle class only on one lists

Tags: javascript, vue.js

im trying to create a todolist with vuejs, adding and removing list is working. I'm struggling now with the -done function- which will toggle a class to append a line-through to a list.

The problem is everytime i toggle the -done button- the style will apply to all lists not only one list, here is my code

```
    .completed{
      text-decoration:line-through;
     }


     <div id="app">
       <input type="text" v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
        <ul>
         <li v-if="!todos.length">no items</li>

         <li v-for="todo in todos">
           <span v-bind:class="{'completed':done}"> {{ todo }}</span>
           <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
           <button v-on:click="toggleC">done</button>
         </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        newTodo : '',
        todos   : [],
        done    : false
      },
      methods: {
        addTodo: function(){
          var text = this.newTodo.trim()
          if (text){
            this.todos.push(text);
            this.newTodo = '';
          }
        },
        removeTodo: function (index){
          this.todos.splice(index, 1)
        },
        toggleC: function(){
          this.done = !this.done
        }
      }
    })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you only have one `done` variable, and it's associated with the Vue instance. Thus either everything is done, or not done. Instead, give each todo it's own `done` property.

When you add a todo, set `done` to false, and set a `text` property to the text value:

```
addTodo: function(){
  var text = this.newTodo.trim()
  if (text){
    this.todos.push({text: text, done: false});
    this.newTodo = '';
  }
},
```

Modify the HTML to pass the current todo in the v-for loop:

```
<li v-for="todo in todos">
  <!-- We conditionally add the 'completed' class based on todo.done -->
  <span v-bind:class="todo.done ? 'completed' : ''"> {{ todo.text }}</span>
  <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>

  <!-- Notice we can pass the current todo to toggleC -->
  <button v-on:click="toggleC(todo)">done</button>
</li>
```

Then, in the `toggleC` method, simply toggle the `done` status of the current todo:

```
toggleC: function(todo){
  todo.done = !todo.done
}
```

Here it is all put together!

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    newTodo : '',
    todos   : [],
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function(){
      var text = this.newTodo.trim()
      if (text){
        this.todos.push({text: text, done: false});
        this.newTodo = '';
      }
    },
    removeTodo: function (index){
      this.todos.splice(index, 1)
    },
    toggleC: function(todo){
      todo.done = !todo.done
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.completed{
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.25/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="newTodo" v-on:keyup.enter="addTodo">
  <ul>
    <li v-if="!todos.length">no items</li>

    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <!-- We conditionally add the 'completed' class based on todo.done -->
      <span v-bind:class="todo.done ? 'completed' : ''"> {{ todo.text }}</span>
      <button v-on:click="removeTodo($index)">X</button>
      
      <!-- Notice we can pass the current todo to toggleC -->
      <button v-on:click="toggleC(todo)">done</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```